# Schedule task to run every time with 1 minute at a time and a delay

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, scheduler

I've, an array of **35 Yahoo WOEIDs** in `woeids.trends_country_capital`, with which I want to fetch twitter trends for respective WOEIDS. Now twitter has a limit of 1 req/min for it's trends API, so I would like to fetch 35 WOEID's trends with **1 at a time/min** and once all done will repeat the process **indefinitely**.

```
node module - cron
```

Here is one code I have tested from many, which definitely won't work as the inner cron won't work. Another solution I've tried is to split the **35** locations in three cron jobs with `15, 15, 5`, but I can't understand how can I make the first cron job wait. When I split, this is the flow I'm hopping to achieve:

```
const worldWide = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '0 */35 * * * *',
  onTick: function() {
    _(woeids.trends_country_capital).forEach(woeid => {
        new CronJob('0 */1 * * * *', function() {
            trendsCountry.get('/trends/place', {id: woeid}, function(error, trends, response) {
                if (!error) {
                    dbCountries.countries.update(
                        { woeid: woeid },
                        {
                            woeid: woeid,
                            trends: trends[0].trends,
                            lastUpdated: new Date().getTime()
                        },
                        { upsert: true },
                        function (err, data) {
                            console.log(err, data);
                        }
                    )
                }
            });
        }, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
    });
  },
  start: false,
  timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
});
```

- Fetch first 15 WOEID's trends and wait for 35 minutes to execute again
- Fetch next 15 trends after 15 minutes of above cron and wait for 35 minutes.
- Fetch next 5 trends after 15 minutes of second job and wait for 35 minutes.